# What is the name of the musical piece that plays in One Piece episode 722 at 13:54?

Tags: one-piece, music

There was a soundtrack piece playing in the episode 722 of *One Piece*. It started playing at 13 minutes and 54 seconds in.  What is the name of that piece?  It starts playing when Luffy rushes Doflamingo saying that once the latter's defeated, everything will be okay.

P.S. If the name of that song specifically is within another song (an example being the piece "Difficult" being composed of both the songs "Shichibukai" and "Mr. Prince"), please specify the song part specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the OST you're looking for is **Sanji vs Captain Honki** and is from [One Piece Movie 7: The Giant Mechanical Soldier of Karakuri Castle.](http://myanimelist.net/anime/465/One_Piece:_Karakurijou_no_Mecha_Kyohei)

It is **Track 35** in the [Movie 7 OST list](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Movie_7_OST_-_Karakuri-jou_no_Mecha-kyohei).

You can listen to the OST [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xRXiYuAqjM)