# What is the name of the song that plays in One Piece episode 722 at 12:28?

Tags: one-piece, music

The question is similar to [this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27987/what-was-the-name-of-the-song-in-one-piece-episode-722) but the song I'm looking for is different. I'm looking for the song that started approximately at 12:28 in episode 722. It begins when Doflamingo begins speaking. The voices cover some parts, but I like the song a lot.

Comment: I haven't double-checked (because I'm @ work) but I have seen the episode yesterday and I think this might be the track you mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBiAA6BMxbU    Please confirm/deny so I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry no this isn't the one i'm looking for.

Comment: If I remember I'll check the episode when I get home then ;)

Comment: Sorry man, couldn't find it, seems nice tho.. Anyway, here's another track I  found that sounded pretty nice, as a consolation prize xD https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgPkVDgjD4M

Answer (score 3):

The OST you're looking for hasn't been released as of yet.

As of now, it's named "Doflamingo's Theme" and you can listen to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9S3iwvaENc).

I'll update this answer once the OST has been officially released.

Answer (score -1):

here it is guys, i found it finally

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6dXdLHj-E0

Comment: Posting a link itself is not considered answering the question. The video could be moved or made unavailabe in which case the information will be lost. Please [edit] your post to include the name of the song.